# 'White bar' on MenuStripDropDown

Tags: c#, winforms, renderer, menustrip

I currently have a custom Render set up for a MenuStrip on a C# windows forms application:

```
        private class HeaderMenuRender : ProfessionalColorTable
    {
        public override Color MenuItemSelectedGradientBegin
        {
            get
            {
                return Color.Gray;
            }
        }

        public override Color MenuItemSelectedGradientEnd
        {
            get
            {
                return Color.Gray;
            }
        }

        public override Color MenuItemPressedGradientBegin
        {
            get
            {
                return Color.Gray;
            }
        }

        public override Color MenuItemPressedGradientEnd
        {
            get
            {
                return Color.Gray;
            }
        }

        public override Color MenuItemBorder
        {
            get
            {
                return Color.Gray;
            }
        }

        public override Color MenuBorder
        {
            get
            {
                return Color.Gray;
            }
        }
    }
```

This is then applied to an existing MenuStrip control on a form to create a Custom render.

However when running the application and making a selection from the menu which is displayed, despite the Menu options being the correct colour, there is a small 'White' (arguably could be 'Control' colour) bar which spans the length of the selected MenuStrip option (indicated in the blue box below):

[image: MenuStrip 'White' Bar]

Is there a particular property of the custom Renderer that I am not including or something I am missing which is setting this specific part of the MenuStrip selected item? The examples I have seen elsewhere do not seem to have this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the above code, it seems you made items `Gray` using `BackColor` property.

You can use override `ToolStripDropDownBackground` to return `Color.Gray`, this removes that while line.

Also you can overriding `ImageMarginGradientBegin`, `ImageMarginGradientMiddle` and `ImageMarginGradientEnd` to make also image/checkbox area `Gray`.

Here is What I added to your codes to get the desired value:

```
public override Color ImageMarginGradientBegin
{
    get { return Color.Gray; }
}

public override Color ImageMarginGradientMiddle
{
    get { return Color.Gray; }
}

public override Color ImageMarginGradientEnd
{
    get { return Color.Gray; }
}

public override Color ToolStripDropDownBackground
{
    get { return Color.Gray; }
}
```

Comment: Quick, simple, clean. Like it. Also is less demanding as you are right, it sets the BackColor of each individual ToolStripMenuItem without necessarily just changing the colour of the MenuStrip itself using a number of different overrides; just looking at it suggests there was a better way to do it as it's not really using gradient for its intended purpose. I've also made the icons gray but I'd rather just remove the icon image margin altogether. Having some issues removing those on sub-menus currently but I want to look at that more first as it's a separate issue.

Comment: You are welcome, By the way you can also vote for an answer when you accept it, it is not compulsory at all but reasonable and recommended, and is your kindness :)

Comment: It's your kindness :)

Comment: Amazing. Just... Amazing.